# Second input value in the text field doesn't change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

My first check of the input value turns out good, and then changes the h1 element's text.

The problem is that I get the same first input, and I don't know how to have these two clicks fired from the same input html element, such that I can have 2 or more separate values to use later on.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    let firstInput;
    let secondInput;
    let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    h1.textContent = 'Enter the number of questions:';

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if(checkValid(document.getElementById('inputField').value)){
            alert('No.1 invalid, try again :)');
        }else{
            firstInput = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
            console.log('First input: ' + firstInput);
            h1.textContent = 'Enter the number of answers per question:';

            $("#submit").click(function(){
                if(checkValid(document.getElementById('inputField').value)){
                    alert('No.2 invalid, try again :)');
                }else{
                    updateInputValue(document.getElementById('inputField').value);
                    secondInput = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
                    console.log('Second input: ' + secondInput);
                    h1.textContent = 'Done';
                }
                console.log('Combined: ', firstInput, secondInput);
            })
        }

        
    })

    function updateInputValue(newValue){
        document.getElementById('inputField').value = newValue;
    }

    function checkValid(inputValue){
        return inputValue.length>2 ||
        isNaN(inputValue[0]) || 
        parseInt(inputValue)===0 || parseInt(inputValue)>50;
    }

})
```

```css
body { 
    min-height: 100vh; 
}

* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <div id="content">
            <h1></h1>
            <input id="inputField">
            <!-- <button id="submit">Submit</button> -->
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>       
</html>
```

Comment: you should not bind a click inside of a click! You are getting multiple clicks bound to the same element.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how to have them separated or iterated over, so that I can have 2 or more different values; I am very new to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I change my code and i think this will works for you :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    let firstInput;
    let secondInput;
    isFirst = true;
    let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    let h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
    h1.textContent = '';
    h1.textContent = 'Enter the number of questions:';

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if(checkValid(document.getElementById('inputField').value)){
            alert('No.1 invalid, try again :)');
        }else{
            
            if(isFirst){
                h2.textContent = '';
              isFirst = false;
              firstInput = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
              console.log('First input: ' + firstInput);
              h1.textContent = 'Enter the number of answers per question:';         
            }else{
                    isFirst = true;
                if(checkValid(document.getElementById('inputField').value)){
                    alert('No.2 invalid, try again :)');
                }else{
                    updateInputValue(document.getElementById('inputField').value);
                    secondInput = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
                    console.log('Second input: ' + secondInput);                    
                    h1.textContent = 'Done';                    
                                    h2.textContent = 'Enter the number of questions:';
                }
                console.log('Combined: ', firstInput, secondInput);
            }        
        }        
    })

    function updateInputValue(newValue){
        document.getElementById('inputField').value = newValue;
    }

    function checkValid(inputValue){
        return inputValue.length>2 ||
        isNaN(inputValue[0]) || 
        parseInt(inputValue)===0 || parseInt(inputValue)>50;
    }

})
```

```css
body { 
    min-height: 100vh; 
}

* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <div id="content">
            <h1></h1>           
            <h2></h2>
            <input id="inputField">
            <!-- <button id="submit">Submit</button> -->
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>       
</html>
```

Comment: my problem is that I want to use the same HTML button to retrieve 2 different values: first the number of questions, then the number of answers per question. And it seems that the first result gets tied to the input.value and I can't change it to something else

Comment: @MyNameIsJeff , i have change the above code please check once. if i miss something then replay.